# How to get related data with nested Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I m working with three models, Tournament, Player, and Result. I m trying to get the result of each Tournament with players and their result **for this tournament**, however, what I m getting is this, Tournament with players and their result **for all Tournaments**.
Tournament and Player have a many-to-many relation.

Tournament Model

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Player Model

```
public function playerTournamentResult()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
}
```

And I m calling

```
public function getActiveTournamentsWithResult(): Collection
{
    return Tournament::with('players.playerTournamentResult')->where('status', true)->get();
}
```

Here is the Result table

```
id | tournament_id | player_id
```

Comment: I don't understand where is your problem, could you please explain more?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert when a player has entries in result table for more than one Tournaments, all of his entries are returning back to each Tournament instances in collections,

Answer (score 0):

You're getting all results from different tournaments because the relation of `hasMany` in **Player** Model is getting all results which explains your query result.

You Use it like this:

```
 public function getActiveTournamentsWithResult(): Collection
 {
    $tournament = Tournament::where('status',true)->get();

    Result::where('tournament_id',$tournament->id)->get();
 }
```